# How to get raw html with absolute links paths when using 'requests-html'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-requests-html

When making a request using the `requests` library to `https://stackoverflow.com`

```
page = requests.get(url='https://stackoverflow.com')
print(page.content)
```

I get the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class="html__responsive html__unpinned-leftnav">
    <head>
        <title>Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build Careers</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
        <link rel="image_src" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"> 
..........
```

These source code here have the absolute paths, but when running the same URL using `requests-html` with js rendering

```
with HTMLSession() as session:
    page = session.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
    page.html.render()
    print(page.content)
```

I get the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>StackOverflow.org</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/interface.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/window.js"></script>
<link href="lib/dock.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="lib/window.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="favicon.gif"/>
..........
```

The links here are relative paths,

How can I get the source code with absolute paths like `requests` when using `requests-html` with js rendering?

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by source-codes and a side by side comparison of difference in the response you get from both packages for a particular link?

Comment: source-codes: raw html of the page, the comparison codes are in the question above. When I use the library ```requests-html``` with js rendering to retrieve the raw HTML response of the page, In this raw HTML source code I get relative links in ```src``` or ```href``` attributes as in ```requests``` library I get the full absolute link.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this in the latest versions. I see the same output in both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably a feature request for the [request-html developers](https://github.com/psf/requests-html/issues). However for now we can achieve this with this hackish solution:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from lxml import etree

with HTMLSession() as session:
    html = session.get('https://stackoverflow.com').html
    html.render()

    # iterate over all links
    for link in html.pq('a'):
        if "href" in link.attrib:
            # Make links absolute
            link.attrib["href"] = html._make_absolute(link.attrib["href"])

    # Print html with only absolute links
    print(etree.tostring(html.lxml).decode())
```

We change the html-objects underlying lxml tree, by iterating over all links and changing their location to absolute using the html-object's private `_make_absolute` function.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on the module in [this link](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) mentions a distinguishment between the absolute and relative links.

Quote:

> Grab a list of all links on the page, in absolute form (anchors
> excluded):

```
r.html.absolute_links
```

Could you try this statement?

Comment: I need the source code that contains absolute paths, not just the links.

Comment: My bad, I think I misunderstood your question.